# How can I get the difference of the dictionary key elements?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am having an array with data as shown below. In this, I need to truncate the hyphen and the part before. Can anyone help me?

```
 var Products = ["50-60", "30-40", "0-10", "20-30", "90-and above", "40-50", "80-90", "70-80", "10-20", "60-70"]
```

I need to get `60` in `50-60`.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what you would like the final data to be, and show what code you attempted to use to complete the task so we can guide you and not do your school assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `flatMap` `products` to get the last element of a hyphen-separated string array created from each element.

```
var truncatedProducts = products.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "-").last }
```

Moreover, **avoid PascalCase** in Swift variable names. Use **camelCase**.

Comment: If he needs 60 in "50-60", do you want `last`? And can you simplify this, e.g. `products.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "-").last }`